Why does a smaller mass gain higher speed in an elastic collision with a larger mass?
In a perfectly elastic collision, if a larger mass (initially moving) collides with a smaller mass (initially stationary), the smaller mass ends up with a much higher speed after the collision. I understand the conservation laws (momentum and kinetic energy) apply, but I’m struggling to understand intuitively why the smaller mass ends up moving faster.
Is there an explanation that ties the outcome to these laws in a way that's easy to grasp? I’d also appreciate any algebraic or diagrammatic insights into how this result emerges from the conservation equations.

Do you find something like The law of the lever to be intuitive? It really isn't so different conceptually if you think about it. It's just that asking for intuition is inherently a bit vague: everyone's intuition works a bit (or a lot) differently.

Can you understand intuitively that if a large car hits a small stationary car vs a larger stationary car,  the smaller car will will end up with a higher speed after the collision?

Thanks all for the insights! Really appreciate it.

The first thing to do is work in the center-of-mass frame ($F$), where:
$$ p_i = -P_i $$
which scatters to:
$$ p_f = -p_i $$
$$ P_f = -P_f $$
(note: this is a 1D problem, so I am not using vector symbols; rather, direction is covered by $\pm$).
That means:
$$ mv_i = -MV_i $$
so that:
$$ v = -\frac M m V $$
meaning:
$$ |v_i| > |V_i| $$
I have $m$ coming from the left with positive velocity, and $M$ from the right with negative velocity.
That is, we start with $v_i>0$ and $V_i<0$, and get:
$$ v_f = -v_f = \frac M m V_i < 0$$
$$ V_f = -V_i > 0$$
If we boost that into your initial frame ($F'$), that requires a Galilean boost with:
$$ u = v_i > 0 $$
So the initial state is:
$$ v'_i = v_i - u = 0 $$
$$ V'_i = V_i - u = -v_i\frac m M - v_i = -v_i(\frac m M +1) $$
The final state is:
$$ v'_f = v_f - u = -v_i - v_i = -2v_i $$
$$ V'_f = V_f - u = -V_i - v_i = v_i(\frac m M -1) $$
So the initial state has one big mass moving at:
$$ S'_i = v_i(1 + \frac m M)$$
and the final state has the small ball with:
$$ s'_f = 2v_i $$
We can factor out the initial speed by looking at the ratio of the final small mass's speed to the initial big mass's speed:
$$ R \equiv \frac{s'_f}{S'_i} = \frac{2}{1+\frac m M} > 1 $$
where the $>$ sign is because $m < M$ and $m/M < 1$.

Because of Newton's Third Law, the masses experience the same magnitude force during the collision. The smaller mass will experience a larger acceleration due to Newton's Second Law. So, in most frames of reference, the smaller mass will end up with the larger velocity.

Think of the large mass as a great big moving wall. Now imagine sitting on the wall. As far as you are concerned, the wall stays still while some small thing (a ping-pong ball or whatever) comes along and bounces off it. In this reference frame the wall just stays still (to very good approximation if its mass is very large) and the ping-pong ball has its velocity reversed (for an elastic collision).
That's the whole story about the collision. Now you just need to see how it will look from a reference frame in which the wall is moving. The ping-pong ball is whacked by the moving wall, a bit like what happens when it is whacked by a table tennis bat in a game of table tennis.
